# How to return derived class type in a function which reside in base class?

Tags: c#, .net

Here is the code.

```
public class EData {
    public static EData All(){
        return null;
    }
}

public class EHouse : EData {

}
```

I don't want the function All in class `EHouse` return `EData` but return `EHouse`.

`EHouse.All()` should return a type of EHouse without coding anything extra in derived classes.

Comment: Umm, even if the `EData.All()` method is `static`?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Yes it must be static, otherwise I could go with extension methods like this `public static A All<A>(this Ai) where A: EData`

Comment: given that you've specifically rejected all the ways to do this, the answer is "you can't."

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield Look at Chris Sinclair answer ;)

Comment: Yeah, you'd think I was Jon Skeet or something. I still don't like my answer. I'm with Michael on this: you really should consider a change of design if possible.

Comment: BTW, kinda outside the scope of the question. But do you really want the `All` method to return a single instance? Wouldn't you expect something like an `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: Your design is wrong. The compiler is talking to you. Listen.

Comment: @Mahdi Chris Sinclair did what you said not to, and changed your derived class. That was on my list of ways you explicitly rejected. :) (It's the best answer, of course, other than fixing your design)

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield Oh yes you are right.. I'm sorry that forgot to mention I could add a one line generic code to my derived class. Once again sorry :)

Comment: What about partial classes?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Please post your answer so I get what you mean ?

Comment: You should be able to work it out from that. Plus you accepted already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can use [Self Referencing Generics](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2008/06/12/generics-the-knee-bone-s-connected-to-the-toe-bone-pattern.aspx) but those can sometimes [cause issues](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx). But you get something like this:

```
public class EData<T> where T : EData<T>
{
    public static T All(){
        return null;
    }
}

public class EHouse : EData<EHouse> 
{

}
```

With usage like:

```
EHouse all = EHouse.All();
```

But not sure if this violates your constraint of "not having to code anything in your derived class" as it changes its inheritance declaration slightly.

Comment: I would heed Eric Lippert's warnings, though. You can achieve pretty much the same effect by adding a new `All` to `EHouse` method that just casts `EData.All()`'s result to `EHouse`, resulting in equivalent code that is much easier to understand, and doesn't seem to promise you type-safety that it doesn't really enforce.

Answer (score 1):

You could try EData having generic type parameters:

```
public class EData<T> 
{
    public static T All()
    { return (T) ..... }
}


public class EHouse : EData<EHouse> { }
```

Comment: Don't feel bad, I'll +1 you :)

Comment: I had to choose Chris because it was first answer. But I also thank you for posting your answer. +1 :)